# lower bound of roots of odd degree polynomial

Tags: polynomials

For a given polynomial $x^{N}+x-1=0$ with $N \geq 3$ and $N$ is odd, we can easily show that it has a unique solution on $(0,1)$. The question is why the root lies in
$$
(1-\frac{\ln N}{N}, 1-\frac{1}{N+1})
$$
I know the upper bound comes from the Newtown method. What about the lower bound. I don't know why we got a logarithmic term here. Can Someone give me a hint to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show that $f(1 - \frac {\ln N}{N}) < 0$ for all $N\ge3$

$f(1 - \frac {\ln N}{N}) = (1 - \frac {\ln N}{N})^N - \frac {\ln N}{N} < 0$

We must show that
$(1 - \frac {\ln N}{N})^N < \frac {\ln N}{N}$

Consider:

$\lim_\limits{N\to \infty} (1 + \frac {k}{N})^N = e^k$

If $N$ is finite $(1 + \frac {k}{N})^N < e^k$

$(1 + \frac {-\ln N}{N})^N < e^{-\ln N} = \frac 1N$

and $\frac 1N < \frac {\ln N}{N}$ for all $N \ge 3$  (really $N\ge e$ but we are assuming than $N$ is an integer)